# error with method, .class missing, OR int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I feel like I am really close to getting what I want accomplished with this class -- but the method getNumbers continues to error -- advising I need .class where i say if numbers[i].isValid(i) -- and if I change it I get "int cannot be dereferenced." Part of my assignment is showing that I can use multiple methods to accomplish something and I know I'm definitely shaky on it. Any advice on that method would be appreciated. It is trying to populate an array and verify each number is between 0 and 59 and also that each number is not a repeating number.

```
import java.util.*;

 public class Luck //edited
{
public int numbers[];

public Luck()
{
    numbers = new int[4];
}

public void greeting()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers, each > 0 and < 59.");
}

public void getNumbers()
{
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[4];

    while(count<5)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number > 0  and < 59");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = reader.nextInt();
        if((isValid(numbers[i]) || isNotRepeat(numbers[]))
        {
            count++;
        System.out.println("Number " + count + " is " + numbers[j]);
        }//end second if
        else TryAnother();
        //else TryAgain();
     }//end for
}//end while
}//end method


     public boolean isNotRepeat(int numbers[]) //edited
 {
     for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
     {
         for(int j=0; j< 5; j++)
         {
         if (i == j)
         return false;

         else return true;
        }//end for
      }//end for
    }


     public boolean isValid (int number)
     {
         number = newNumber;
         if (newNumber < 0 || newNumber > 59)

         return false;
     }



    public void showNumbers(int numbers[])
    {
        int count = 0;
        //int numbers[] = new int[4];
        //int i;

         for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
         {
         System.out.println("Number " + count + 1 + " is " + numbers[0]);
        }
    }

    public void goodLuck()
    {
        System.out.println("Good luck!");
    }

 }//end class
```

Comment: the `isRepeat` method will always return `true`, because in the 1st iteration both `i` and `j` are `0`. `isValid()` probably does not compile...

Comment: After Edit: The `isNotRepeat` method will always return `false`, because in the 1st iteration both `i` and `j` are 0. isValid() does not compile because `newNumber` is undefined and the method has no return statement if the `if` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two visible errors in your code:

1 Your **constructor Name** should be same as your **class name**.

```
public Luck()
```

should be

```
public Lucky()
```

2 you cant invoke **isValid()** and **isNotRepeat** on an **int primitive**.

if you just want to check if an number is valid, just do

```
        if(isValid(i)) or if(isNotReapeat(array))
```

### EDIT:

change

```
if((isValid(numbers[i]) || isNotRepeat(numbers[]))
```

to

```
 if((isValid(numbers[i]) || isNotRepeat(numbers)) // you dont need the brackets, you only need to pass the reference variable
```

Comment: I updated the method in the question and still have same .class error. I really appreciate your feedback...what would you advise?

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have a lot of work but you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`numbers` is an `int[]` (array of `int`). In several places in your code, you are trying to call methods on the elements of `numbers`, for example here:

```
if(numbers[i].isValid(i))

if (numbers[j].isNotRepeat(numbers[]))
```

That is not going to work, because you cannot call methods such as `isValid` and `isNotRepeat` on an `int`. Also, the second line quoted above isn't even valid Java syntax (what do you mean when you try to pass `numbers[]` to a method?).

You probably meant something like this:

```
if(isValid(numbers[i]))
```

(Where's the method `isNotRepeat`?).

Comment: Oh thanks... I meant to rename and change the IsRepeat() method but I got wrapped up in all the issues with GetNumbers...this is what IsNotRepeat should look like...